# Finding and downloading all available Win2008 R2 and W7-32bit patches (without using WSUS)

Tags: patch-management

Is there a way to find and download all available MS patches for:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
- Windows 7 (32-bits) SP1

Without using WSUS or the 'Windows update' tool within the O/S?

I basically want to find and download all available patches that were made available following SP1 to-date and going forward.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WSUS Offline](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) will get you most of the way there.  It's a project that will use the update information from MS's Microsoft Update servers to determine what updates to download, what's been superseded, and can create ISOs or USB sticks.  You just rerun it every month and it grabs the newest information and updates.

This is a 3rd party tool, it's not made by Microsoft, and not related to their Windows Server Update Services (WSUS).

It can also install DirectX runtimes, .NET Frameworks, Internet Explorer, Service Packs, Security Essentials, C++ Runtimes, PowerShell, and updates for Office 2003/2007/2010 as well as Windows XP/2003/Vista/7/2008.

Because it only installs security updates (the same set that [Microsoft's Baseline Security Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184924) checks) Windows Update/Microsoft Update will still report a number of important updates that require installation, but the system will be secure.  You can also customize the program and specify extra updates to download and install (or blacklist particular updates if they're problematic in your configuration).

Comment: hi, can you use WSUS to download updates from W7 and W2008R2 while hosting WSUS on a W2003 machine? Also, once updated are downloaded, can they be used individually by running them manually on the target computers or will the updates have to be applied strictly with WSUS. thx

Comment: Not sure whether you ask about the real WSUS, or the suggested “WSUS Offline Update“ tool (which, BTW, can download updates from a local WSUS server too), but both of them can download updates for all systems currently supported by Microsoft (and WSUS Offline Update does not even need a server OS to run). Manually running updates for Windows would be possible (Office updates are harder — they are in *.cab files instead of *.exe intended for manual download).

Comment: Wah OK I didn't realize that "WSUS Offline" is not MS WSUS in offline mode. hehehe.. COOL APP! Many thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @afrazier: WSUS Offline Update includes only security updates (the same set as checked by MBSA), and does not include a bunch of “reliability” and extra functionality updates (apparently Extended Protection for Authentication falls in this category). Also the 7.0 release misses KB2564958 (which is already fixed in svn). And updates which are not picked automatically may be specified in custom lists.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov: Thanks for the information -- I've updated my answer with those items for extra clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can download all of them directly.

In the [Microsoft Security Bulletins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin) website you can filter by Operating System, type of Update etc and you will have a link will all updates available based on your criteria.

This could works for you. It's very simple to find all available updates for an OS after its last Service Pack.

With some time and creativity, if you need it, maybe you can write a PowerShell script to fetch the website and download all of them in bulk.